# FileNotFoundException after file created to stream output

Tags: java, android, filestream, crashlytics

I recently implemented Crashlytics and am walking thru a veritable cornucopia of crash logs. One has me a bit puzzled. In the log is shows that I could not open a file to stream to (specifically to write a JPG photo I took), however one line before that I (believe) I successfully created it. The exception(s) from Crashlytics:

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException
/storage/emulated/0/mycompany/9311ebcb-4dd5-493c-8fbd-46b242d4991d/b9a9a18e-0cd9-468d-83f3-7466b65485f7.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
 raw
libcore.io.IoBridge.open (IoBridge.java:409)
java.io.FileOutputStream.<init> (FileOutputStream.java:73)
com.invocore.mycompany.utility.Utilities.saveImageJPEG (Utilities.java:698)
com.invocore.mycompany.utility.Utilities.saveImageJPEG (Utilities.java:685)
com.invocore.mycompany.utility.Utilities.saveImage (Utilities.java:634)
com.invocore.mycompany.CameraCaptureActivity.savePhoto (CameraCaptureActivity.java:338)
com.invocore.mycompany.CameraCaptureActivity.access$300 (CameraCaptureActivity.java:39)
com.invocore.mycompany.CameraCaptureActivity$SaveTask.doInBackground (CameraCaptureActivity.java:266)
com.invocore.mycompany.CameraCaptureActivity$SaveTask.doInBackground (CameraCaptureActivity.java:246)
android.os.AsyncTask$2.call (AsyncTask.java:288)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
Caused by libcore.io.ErrnoException
libcore.io.Posix.open (Posix.java)
java.io.FileOutputStream.<init> (FileOutputStream.java:73)
com.invocore.mycompany.utility.Utilities.saveImageJPEG (Utilities.java:698)
com.invocore.mycompany.utility.Utilities.saveImageJPEG (Utilities.java:685)
com.invocore.mycompany.utility.Utilities.saveImage (Utilities.java:634)
com.invocore.mycompany.CameraCaptureActivity.savePhoto (CameraCaptureActivity.java:338)
com.invocore.mycompany.CameraCaptureActivity.access$300 (CameraCaptureActivity.java:39)
com.invocore.mycompany.CameraCaptureActivity$SaveTask.doInBackground (CameraCaptureActivity.java:266)
com.invocore.mycompany.CameraCaptureActivity$SaveTask.doInBackground (CameraCaptureActivity.java:246)
android.os.AsyncTask$2.call (AsyncTask.java:288)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:841)
```

Here's the source code:

```
public static void saveImageJPEG(Bitmap image, int width, int height, String filename, String directory, int quality)
{
    Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, width, height, true);
    OutputStream outStream = null;
    // Only add extension if we need to
    if (!filename.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg")) {
        filename = filename + ".jpg";
    }

    try {
        File file = new File(directory, filename);
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        scaled.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outStream);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        Utilities.logException(e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (outStream != null) {
            try {
                outStream.flush();
                outStream.close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                // Ignore for now
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My uses-permissions from my `AndroidManifest.xml` are:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
```

The exception is happening at `outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);` but I would expect it to have had an error when I attempted to create the file itself in which to stream the output.

Probably missing something very obvious...

Comment: Did you have write external storage permission in your manifest?

Comment: Sorry - yes I do. I cannot replicate this issue locally, though obviously it is happening out in production to someone...I have posted the uses-permissions above...maybe I am missed something there.

Comment: How did you get the `directory` when call `saveImageJPG`? `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`?

Comment: Yes - ultimately:  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the directory you are referring to is app-private or not. I encountered a similar issue and solved it by fixing the max-sdk parameter.
You can look for the section "Saving files that are app-private" here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Answer (score 0):

`FileNotFoundException` on an *output* file means a *directory* wasn't found.

Comment: That could be a possibility. Though it raises even more questions. Currently we are storing our media in a directory that is not app-private. Perhaps the user is deleting the directory? I did see that recently. Guess my only solution is to make it app private, though aren't there physical limits to the size of the data? We can have lots and lots of data.